# Count points inside sphere

Tags: combinatorics, nonlinear-optimization

I have a question that seems easy at first look, but it's not.

Let's say we have **n** dimension space. There is a sphere of **1** radius.
Now we divide space on dots equaly on a distance $\varepsilon$. You can imagine it like squares in school notebook.

Here is [graphical representation in 2 dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuOt7.jpg)

The question is how many points (intersections of lines in school notebook representation) lie in sphere?

In other words if we have such formula: $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2\le1$
Each of $x_i$ lies in interval $[-1;1]$ divided on equal segments with $\varepsilon$ length.
Then how many sets of **n** values of $x_i$ can we give that inequality is true.

Comment: Of course in case $\varepsilon$ is *little* we can say it is $\pi(1/\varepsilon)^2$, but what about exact solution?

Comment: I don't think there is an exact formula, but you can derive upper and lower limits for the number of points using the Volume formula (one time with radius $R+\epsilon$ and one time with radius $R-\epsilon$)